# Enabling partial name input to return values in c#

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a c# web service that takes an `String` input and checks the input vs a text document full of `Strings`.

It works as follows, lets  say I input "Australia" into the input, the service will return `"Australia"`. However if I also input Aus (or aus, currently made it case insensitive) it should also return `"Australia"`.

On the other hand if I input "tra", it shouldn't return Australia, only Strings that their first 3 indexes are "tra". (If it was Ch, it should return China, Chad... etc)

Currently my code looks like

```
 public String countryCode(String input)
    {
        StringBuilder strings = new StringBuilder("", 10000);
        String text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("countryCodes.txt"));
        String[] countries = Regex.Split(text, "#");


        int v;
        for (v = 0; v < countries.Length; v++)
        {
            if (countries[v].ToUpper().Contains(input) || countries[v].ToLower().Contains(input))
            {
                bool c = countries[v].ToUpper().Contains(input);
                bool b = countries[v].ToLower().Contains(input);
                if (b == true || c == true)
                {
                        strings.Append(countries[v] + " ");
                  }



                else
                {
                    strings.Append("Country not found");
                    break;
                }

            }



        }
        String str = strings.ToString();
        return str;
    }
```

This is a start, but I am really having trouble comparing the indexes of strings.

My question is how can I construct something to check `countries[v][0]` vs `input[0]`, if its the same, then check `[1]` and `[1]`, and so on, until they aren't the same or `input.Length` is exceeded then return values appropriate?

Comment for clarifications if needed

Regards

Comment: Any reason you don't just use the Startswith method to to see if a string starts with a particular pattern?

Comment: Only even programmed in java, didn't even realize there was a Startswith method :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your loop can be reduced to:

```
var valids = new List<String>();
foreach(String c in countries)
   if(c.ToUpper().StartsWith(input.ToUpper()))
       valids.Add(c);

return (valids.Any()) ? String.Join(",",valids) : "No Matches";
```

or LINQ:

```
var valids = countries.Select(c => c.ToUpper().StartsWith(input.ToUpper())).ToList();
return (valids.Any()) ? String.Join(",",valids) : "No Matches";
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a lot more concise...cheers and the StartsWith method I was unaware, thanks to Jonesy and R0MANARMY